# Why twitter widget not showing in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, twitter

When I set overflow:hidden to .container for masorny grid, widget not showing.
With overflow:visible it's work fine.

Example:

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Tankerxyz/pen/aywOEv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For chrome need reset "transform" prop for widgets, like:

```
.widget-item {
    transform: initial !important;
}
```